# $\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}G$ - module.

Tags: modules, group-actions, group-rings

Let G group. Recently i read that $\mathbb{Z}$ can be considered as $\mathbb{Z}G$- module with the trivial action, such that :
$$\forall x\in \mathbb{Z}G,\ z\in \mathbb{Z}:\quad x\cdot z:=z$$
But if that is true then for every $x,x'\in \mathbb{Z}G$ and $z\in \mathbb{Z}$ we have that
$$(x+x')\cdot z=x\cdot z+x'\cdot z\Rightarrow z=z+z.$$
Where is the problem about the  definition of this action ?

Comment: You define the action by elements of $G$ that way then extend by linearity.

Comment: *Each element of $G$* acts trivially... not "each element of $\mathbb ZG$."  Incidentally, this is just the $\mathbb ZG$ module structure on $\mathbb ZG/\omega(\mathbb ZG)\cong \mathbb Z$ (The notation $\omega(\mathbb ZG)$ denotes the augmentation ideal, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct definition is to define $g\cdot x =x$ for all $g \in G$ and $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Then, for an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{Z}G$, we let it act by the obvious linear extension. So, given $w=\sum_{g\in G} a_gg$ with $a_g \in \mathbb{Z}$ we would define
$$
w\cdot x = \left( \sum_{g\in G} a_gg\right) \cdot x = \sum_{g \in G} a_g (g\cdot x) = \sum_{g \in G} a_gx.
$$
So, in your case, for two group elements $g_1, g_2$ you would have
$$
(g_1+g_2) \cdot x = g_1 \cdot x + g_2 \cdot x = x+x.
$$
This is not $x$ because $g_1+g_2$ is not an element of $G$, but a linear combination in $\mathbb{Z}G$.

This is exactly analogous to defining a linear map on vector space $V$ by defining it solely on a basis and then just saying "we extend it to all of $V$ by linearity."  Here, $G$ is the "basis" of $\mathbb{Z}G$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ is the "scalars."

Comment: This  makes sense. Thank you very much for your responce !